# Finding Extreme points - Convex hull with C#

Tags: c#, computational-geometry

I want to find Extreme points and the output must be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDtmd.png)
but my code give me  [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHQUj.png)

So , i want to change it to give me correct output , How can i do that ? Thank you very much!

```
 public override void Run(List<Point> points, List<Line> lines, List<Polygon> polygons, ref List<Point> outPoints, ref List<Line> outLines, ref List<Polygon> outPolygons)
        {
            List<Point> opoints = new List<Point>();
            HelperMethods helper = new HelperMethods();

            for (int i = 0; i < points.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < points.Count; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < points.Count; k++)
                    {
                        if (points[i] != points[j] && points[j] != points[k] && points[i] != points[k])
                        {
                            for (int p = 0; p < points.Count; p++)
                            {
                                if (i != p && j != p && k != p)
                                {
                                    if (HelperMethods.PointInTriangle(points[p], points[i], points[j], points[k]) == Enums.PointInPolygon.Inside)
                                    {
                                        opoints.Add(points[p]);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            outPoints = opoints;
        }
```

Comment: Have you at least tried debugging the code? I sense this should be straightforward tweak-compile-debug-repeat routine.
Also there are some pieces of code that nobody knows how they are implemented - e.g. `HelperMethods.PointInTriangle`.  So if you can fill in what you have tried and what the magic PointInTriangle does, it might be easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks for answering but sounds like you don't understand me good.I have list called "opoints" , which contain points inside convex hull and i want points outside not inside , like images that i have attached in my post :) @Fanick

Comment: Yes, I understood very well. The goal is very clear from those pictures. By debugging I didn't mean that there is something broken, I should have chosen the term 'stepping through your code'. This way you would get the feeling of what the code does or does not do and how to change it in a way that it does what you need it to do.

Comment: What are the things that you tried to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: I solved my issue , Thanks for supporting me. I will write my answer here , maybe another one have the same issue and help him.Thank you very much.

Comment: Your method is horribly inefficient, apparently of order O(n^4). You should switch to the Monotone Chain method. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain

Answer (score -1):

If anyone have the same issue, i solved my issue and will share solution to help others.

In `opoints` list , there are all points inside the convex hull :

[image]

But our job to find outer points of Convex hull : 
[image]

So , we can do that by loop over all points and display only points that doesn't exist in `opoints` list .

Here's the code:

```
for (int m = 0; m < points.Count; m++)
{
   if (!opoints.Contains(points[m]))
       outPoints.Add(points[m]);
}
```